# why is my fluid grid layout not working?

Tags: html, css

i am just starting the design so I'm trying to set modules to a pixel width. why aren't the modules taking up more space of their height. should i add height? if so in percentages or pixels or ems? what am i missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title> AZKF </title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
</head>
<body class="page">

    <div class="blog">

        <div class="main">

        </div>
        <div class="other">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
.page {
    width: 960px;
    margins: 0 auto;
}

.page {
    background-color: #3a434a;
}

.blog {
    width: 900px;
    margins: 0 auto;
}

.blog {
    background-color: blue;

}

.main {
    background-color: green;
    width: 566px;
    margins: 0 auto;
    float: left;

}

.other {
    backpround-color: black;
    width: 331px;
    margins: 0 auto;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: which element's height you're talking about????

Comment: do i need to add height to all of the containing elements?

Comment: You don't set height anywhere, so elements are taking as mush space as it needs. Use `html, body{height: 100%} body{min-height: 100%;} blog{height: 100%;}`

Comment: @Justinas ok thanks i know its not a height problem now... but my other div containers aren't appearing (just the main body container). is it because they are empty? any ideas?

Comment: First of all there are typos in your css. It not `margins`, its margin and also its `background-color: black;` not `backpround-color: black;`. You won't get any result with this html and css because there is no content in html. Add dummy content or add height to each divs to see the result

Comment: @james thanks for the help, i overlooked the margins and i didn't realize about the empty containers. you're right about the empty containers without content. can i ask you.. why it works this way? any insights?

Comment: @DerikSScott it simply because when there is no content the height of the container is zero.

Answer (score 0):

try this css:

```
.page {
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .blog {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }



    .main {
        background-color: green;
        float: left;
        width: 60%;
    }
    .other {
        background-color: black;
        width: 40%;
        float: right;
    }
```

Comment: i tired this css , the .main and .other background colors are still not appearing. when i look in the inspector the width value is correct but the height value is set to 0.

Comment: ok u can try this css..page {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 960px;
}.blog {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 900px;
}.main {
    background-color: green;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: 566px;
}.other {
    float: right;
    height: 20px;
    width: 331px;
} or if u don't want to add the height then just add some text inside your div.

Answer (score 0):

use the follow code

```
.page { 
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color: #3a434a;
}
.blog { 
    position: relative;
    width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.blog {
    background-color: blue;
} 
.main {
    background-color: green;
    width: 66.66666667%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
    border:1px solid yellow;
    padding:30px 0px;
}
.other {
    background-color: black;
    width: 32.33333333%;
    border:1px solid red;
    margins: 0 auto;
    padding:30px 0px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: In this style sheet padding and border are mention so you could know how its will come up